# Tim Sort - where to find some good documentation?

Tags: mergesort

Anyone knows where to find some documentation about Tim Sort using examples and probably pseudocode to describe it? I'm interested in how it works but the docs I've found so far, well, err, are not very pleasant to read ^^.

Comment: What don't you find pleasant, and what documentation have you found so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the documentation : http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt

Comment: Hope to see some better illustrated version of Tim Sort

Answer (score 2):

It is well described in a wikipedia article:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort